# Is there any use for non-predictive method?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-physics, phenomenology

"Scientific method", as controversial as this phrase is, almost always contains the need for predictions - a theory will be scientific if it's (among other things, but at the very least) able to predict future phenomenons.

I'm reading Husserl's Crisis of European Sciences (haven't finished it yet), in which Husserl presents the accomplishment of the "Galilean technique which is called physics" as "nothing but *prediction* [Husserl italicized] extended to infinity". Then he goes on to state that actually everything in our life are predictions (where he also previously compares prediction to induction) - "seeing, perceiving, is essentially having-something-itself and at the same time having-something-in-advance... All praxis, with its projects, involves inductions [or- predictions]".

Now if we take Husserl's presentation of physics as "nothing but predictions", and life as always involving predictions, we can ask - is there any use for a method that doesn't involve predictions? [Note- I'm talking about natural phenomenons' research.]

Furthermore, if we're not going with Husserl's comparison of induction and prediction, or, if we simply don't accept that everything in life involves induction/prediction, but still take his presentation of physics, we can ask if a method that doesn't involve predictions can actually be useful and unearth certain aspects of reality we could not with the current methods that do rely on (or, requires) predictions?

[I suspect that the transcendental phenomenology that Husserl suggests, which I have yet to read but have a general sense of, is somewhat in line with this thinking, so I might just need to read ahead but the question simply struck me so I had to go here and ask. But in any case - even if Husserl's phenomenology is an example, what I'd like to recieve is either more examples (not necessary, if there are) with further explanation of the idea in the question, or a refutation of the question.]

Comment: Science does not need to predict, and when it predicts it is not necessarily future phenomena, think of archeology or paleontology. Physics is a poor model for science at large.  Husserl's Crisis was written in his waning years and under heavy influence of Heidegger. His grasp of science of the time was not what it was in his early life, ironically, the Crisis was written when the crisis in physics was already resolved. It is more a reflection of the crisis of Husserl's phenomenology reaching its limitations. Non-predictive side of phenomenology is partly incorporated into cognitive psychology

Comment: I agree on your point that prediction doesn't necessarily need to be for the future, but the idea is that it needs to be for the future *of the research*, i.e. even in archeology if we come up with a theory to explain a phenomenon, we'd also like it to "predict" our future findings - the theory's success will be partially determined by its ability to help us find more phenomenons and provide patterns about them. While I'm not very familiar with what you're saying about Husserl, I do know that some consider this to be one of (if not *the*) his most important works.

Comment: @Conifold also, maybe that's a question for a different post, but how was the crisis resolved?

Comment: Difficult to answer a question at this level of generality... For sure history has a scientific approach: facts, documents, explanation and it is clearly aimed at *understanding*. Thus, it is clearly useful in order to "unearth certain aspects of reality"; but it has no predictive force.

Comment: Given any finite amount of data (information), there necessarily exists a mathematical function (theory) that fits it. So, the problem with non-predictive methods is that you can always find one, but it may tell you nothing useful.

Comment: @barrycarter where did you bring that from? Any source? That sounds extremely debatable. Unless maybe if you define "function" very loosely and/or "information" very strictly.

Comment: You now watered down "prediction" to a point of vacuity, any knowledge,  if it is true, "predicts" that something happens. The crisis was resolved by the development of relativity and quantum mechanics. Crisis is influential in certain continental circles (for similar reasons so is Heidegger) but it is not a work by Husserl, it was assembled from disparate notes by editors after his death. Roughly, it reflects Husserl's disappointment that sciences did not follow his phenomenological programme for them introduced in Logical Investigations (1900) and reiterated in 1920-s.

Comment: @Conifold I don't see how what I said is similar to what you inferred. There can be a something I'd call present knowledge, which will be of only current events. I think you'll agree that any knowledge that will say something about newly found events (note again- not future in the meaning of the time those events took place, but future in the meaning that my observation of them is new) will contain prediction. If you'll disagree on that I'd like you to define prediction. And about what you say about Husserl, can I have any source for that?

Comment: There is no such thing as "present knowledge" because there is no such thing as "present", all words in a language are type words and therefore refer to a class of events, some of which are in the future, some in the past. I suggest that *you* try to define "prediction" coherently and I suspect that any attempt to do it meaningfully while pinning it on all of "science" will fail, indeed the conception of "science as a whole" in your many questions seems to me misguided. There is extensive secondary literature on late Husserl and writing of the Crisis.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss Well, I'm defining information as "something that can be assigned numerical values", and was thinking of polynomial fitting or spline fitting, for example.

Comment: @Conifold you're still placing it on a time perception perspective, while I'm talking more in the logical process perspective. Obviously I don't mean "present time" in the normal sense because everything that is present is actually in the past and that's definitely not what I'm going for. If you'd like my general definition, although I have already given it, it'd be somewhat formally this: if a supposes b, then later research confirms b to be true, it has "successfully predicted" it. Usually the more predictive a theory get, it is considered to be better. I hope that's enough.

Comment: I do not follow what "logical present" is or how this will be different for any knowledge. If it is true it "predicts" something.

Comment: @Conifold I'm sorry, "logical present" isn't the right term. Perhaps "epistemologically present" may be better? I can differentiate between a knowledge I acquired now to a knowledge I can predict that'll be acquired later. The newly acquired knowledge itself doesn't have to be earlier or later than the previously acquired knowledge, only my own acquisition of it. I hope this is better phrased.

Answer (score 2):

What about painting, or music? To say they are about prediction reveals the hollowness of

> is there any use for a method that doesn't involve predictions?

which is clearly aimed at providing priveleging science over everything else. Not just music, but mathematics, language, are expressive, creative, and seeking of the edge between predictable and unpredictable - the complex, the fractal.

Comment: I edited that in, but I wanted to note that I meant natural phenomenons.

Comment: Just sounds like scientism to me. What about boundary issues like consciousness? Natural phenomena, or creative art?

Comment: well surely all science (more generally, *everything*) can be considered art, but I doubt you'd want to take that definition of art for an academic field.